# Table iteration in React conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs

If an array has a length, I want to iterate it and display its data as a table.

Sadly, I can't wrap the iteration inside of the table. 
The array is the result of an API call. Each item is an array that contains an object. It looks like this:

```
myArray: [0[{
           name: "Joe",
           surname: "Smith",
           email: "joe@smith.com"
          }], 
          1[{
           name: "Jack",
           surname: "Warren",
           email: "jack@warren.com"
          }]
         ]
```

Here is the code:

```
class SearchResult extends Component {
    render(){
        const {myArray} = this.props;

        return(
             <section className="SearchResult">
                 <h3>Results</h3>

             {myArray.length === 0 ? (<h3>No Result</h3>):

           myArray.map((oneData, index) =>{
              return (
                  <div key={index} className="result">

                      <h4>{oneData.name}</h4>
                      <p>{oneData.surname}</p>
                      <p>{oneData.email}</p>
                  </div>
             )})
          }
              </section>
          )}}

    export default SearchResult;
```

When I wrap myArray.map(oneData, index) etc. with a table, React goes mad. How would you fix that?

My idea was:

```
class SearchResult extends Component {
    render(){
        const {myArray} = this.props;

        return(
             <section className="SearchResult">
                 <h3>Results</h3>

             {myArray.length === 0 ? (<h3>No Result</h3>):

           (<table>
            <tr>
              <td>name</td>
              <td>surname</td>
              <td>email</td>
            </tr>

           myArray.map((oneData, index) =>{
              return (
                  <div key={index} className="result">
                    <tr>
                        <td><h4>{oneData.name}</h4></td>
                        <td><p>{oneData.surname}</p></td>
                        <td><p>{oneData.email}</p></td>
                    </tr>
                  </div>
             )})
         <table>
          }
              </section>
          )}}

    export default SearchResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause `oneData` in map is array not object like this

```
[{
  name: "Joe",
  surname: "Smith",
  email: "joe@smith.com"
}]
```

so `oneData.name` value is undefined it should be `oneData[0].name`.So you can fix by use `array destructuring`.

Replace `myArray.map((oneData, index)...` with `myArray.map(([oneData], index)...`